# Artifactory Custom Base URL give 404 page not found error

Tags: artifactory

Running Artifactory Pro 7.2.1 in a Docker container.

I can access Artifactory via `http://${IP}:port`, but when I try to access Artifactory login page or repos I setup via the Custom Base URL I setup `https://${hostname}` I get a 404 page not found.

I can ssh to the host name and log into the Artifactory server (Linux Centos VM).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Custom Base URL in Artifactory doesn't configure any internal redirections or configures the application to listen on another port.

Unless you have a reverse-proxy to listen on the configured Custom Based URL and redirect to the Artifactory IP and port, there is probably nothing to resolve them.

A possible approach to achieve this can be using [NGINX](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+NGINX).

Comment: Under Http Settings - Reverse Proxy Settings, Server Provider is set to Embedded Tomcat. I was hoping that would take care of the reverse-proxy. I will setup a NGINX reverse-proxy.